# Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError Class 'app\link' not found

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I already started using `Laravel` and I have this problem

> "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError Class 'app\link' not found".

under the app folder, I have a `link` file but it's empty and not in PHP format, what I need to do in this case?

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If your file is under app folder but it is not in PHP format, you have the answer for your question. Laravel will not recognize it as a class if the file isn't a php file. Just rename is to `Link.php` and add a basic structure, like this one:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

class Link
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    
    }
}
```